# Can my question be marked as not duplicate?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I had asked [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38167/how-should-i-plan-a-life-as-a-professional-writer-author-novelist) question quite a while back, I had not chosen the answer for a long time as all the answers were helpful to me and it was proving difficult to choose one.

Then I got the message near my question about a possible dupe. In a serious lack of judgement and confusion, I accepted it so. But I think it's not a dupe and a different question.

Can you please remove the duplicate tag from it?

Comment: Looking at the comments, you and a couple of others apparently voted to reopen it, and yet it has no reopen votes as of right now. I'll vote to reopen it myself.

Comment: @F1Krazy thank you very much for that. (sorry for the delayed reply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has received one community reopen vote and therefore should be in the community reopen review queue.